# program freezes when querying directions with GoogleMapsAPI

Tags: vb.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I have another function that GEOcodes the address and that is submitting and returning as expected but the Directions API freezes my program. I is being submitted properly because I can see it going out and I see the correct return in Fiddler but my program locks up and won't continue past the .Query.

here is a snipit

```
Public Sub _GetDirections(ByVal inAddr As String)

    Dim req As New DirectionsRequest
    Dim resp As New DirectionsResponse

    req.Origin = "new york"
    req.Destination = "florida"
    req.TravelMode = TravelMode.Driving
    req.DepartureTime = DateTime.Now
    req.ApiKey = APIKEY

    resp = GoogleMapsApi.GoogleMaps.Directions.Query(req)
    Dim Route As Route = resp.Routes.First()
    Dim Leg As Leg = Route.Legs.First()
    For Each s As [Step] In Leg.Steps
        Console.WriteLine(StripHTML(s.HtmlInstructions))

        Dim localIcon = s.TransitDetails?.Lines?.Vehicle?.LocalIcon
        If localIcon <> vbNull Then
            Console.WriteLine("Local sign: " + localIcon)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

It gets stuck on resp = GoogleMapsApi.GoogleMaps.Directions.Query(req) never moves to the next break point but fiddler sees this

```
4106
{
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJvypWkWV2wYgR0E7HW9MTLvc",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 40.7291471,
               "lng" : -74.0062258
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 27.6490247,
               "lng" : -81.6862869
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Map data ©2017 Google, INEGI",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1,153 mi",
                  "value" : 1855338
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "17 hours 7 mins",
                  "value" : 61628
               },
               "duration_in_traffic" : {
                  "text" : "17 hours 17 mins",
                  "value" : 62248
               },
```

So I'm not sure why visual the results aren't actually returning to the program... I'm sure I'm probably doing something stupid.

Comment: alright, so I've figured out that it only freezes when trying to use it in a Windows Forms Application. I created a new Module application and it works fine, I created a new windows forms application with nothing else in it and it freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I had to run it on a separate thread from the GUI. Not sure why, it wasn't a taxing function and it didn't take long to return but once I created a Background worker for it and ran it Async it ran perfectly. Hope this helps someone else using googles mapping api.